# Poppler installation

Tags: dpkg, build, evince, glib

I downloaded the new poppler 0.15 tar ball and i built it from source successfully but when trying

```
dpkg -l | grep poppler
```

it outputs

```
ii  libpoppler-dev                                0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF rendering library -- development files
ii  libpoppler-glib-dev                           0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF rendering library -- development files (GLib interface)
ii  libpoppler-glib4                              0.12.4-1ubuntu1                                    PDF rendering library (GLib-based shared library)
ii  libpoppler-glib5                              0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF rendering library (GLib-based shared library)
ii  libpoppler5                                   0.12.4-1ubuntu1                                    PDF rendering library
rc  libpoppler6                                   0.14.2.is.0.14.1-0ubuntu1                          PDF rendering library
ii  libpoppler7                                   0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF rendering library
ii  poppler-utils                                 0.14.3-0ubuntu1.1                                  PDF utilitites (based on libpoppler)
```

So AFAIK this means that the new version is not installed !!

Comment: What does `which poppler` say ?

Comment: What commands did you use to build from source?

Comment: ./configure && make && make install  ...
i figured out the problem .. dpkg will only show the binary *.debpackages installed if you just ./configure && make && make install it will not show up in dpkg. so i put this prefix ./configure --prefix=/usr while building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. dpkg will only show the binary `*.debpackages` as installed. If you just `./configure && make && make install` it will not show up in dpkg. so I put this prefix `./configure --prefix=/usr` while building.